# Update visual data between forms

Tags: c#

I have a ListView. Each item of the ListView linked to an object (class).
I want to update object data on other forms on click on an item.
So I’ve implemented Observable Pattern.
Interfaces:

```
public interface IObserver
{
    void Update(object obj);
}


public interface IObservable
{
    void AddObserver(IObserver observer);
    void NotifyObservers(object obj);
    void RemoveObserver(IObserver observer);
}
```

Main Form:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form, IObservable
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    PersonDataForm pdfrm;

    private List<IObserver> _Observers = new List<IObserver>();

    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Person pers1 = new Person { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Smith", ID = 307566438, Company = "EMG", Position = "Manager" };
        Person pers2 = new Person { FirstName = "Jack", LastName = "Broun", ID = 308567430, Company = "EMG", Position = "Accounter" };
        Person pers3 = new Person { FirstName = "Lisa", LastName = "Mishli", ID = 307316432, Company = "EMG", Position = "Teller" };

        ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem { Text = pers1.FirstName, Tag = pers1 };
        ListViewItem item2 = new ListViewItem { Text = pers2.FirstName, Tag = pers2 };
        ListViewItem item3 = new ListViewItem { Text = pers3.FirstName, Tag = pers3 };

        listViewPersons.Items.Add(item1);
        listViewPersons.Items.Add(item2);
        listViewPersons.Items.Add(item3);

        pdfrm = new PersonDataForm();
        AddObserver(pdfrm);
        pdfrm.Show();

    }

    public void AddObserver(IObserver observer)
    {
        _Observers.Add(observer);
    }

    public void NotifyObservers(object obj)
    {
        foreach (var observer in _Observers)
        {
            observer.Update(obj);
        }
    }

    public void RemoveObserver(IObserver observer)
    {
        _Observers.Remove(observer);
    }

    private void listViewPersons_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NotifyObservers(this. listViewPersons.SelectedItems[0].Tag as Person);                                   }

    public void Update(object obj)
    {
        Person pers = obj as Person;
        listViewPersons.SelectedItems[0].Text = pers.FirstName;

    }

}
```

Child Form:

```
  public partial class PersonDataForm : Form, IObserver
    {

        public PersonDataForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void Update(object obj)
        {
            Person pers = obj as Person;
            textBoxFirstName.Text = pers.FirstName;
            textBoxLastName.Text = pers.LastName;
        }

    }
```

It works fine. On click on an item in MainForm, text boxes updated in PersonDataForm. But how can I reverse it. On text change in text box in PersonDataForm I want to change the item data of MainForm. Should I implement both IObservable and IObserver in every form? It seems quite messy. 
May be there is a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is all a matter of design. If your design should implement an `IObservable` pattern in the first place, then, yes, you got your answer there already: It ought to work both ways.

But: Why would you want to use this involved pattern in the first place? You are writing a GUI program. This means that all events are triggered by a user clicking on the tree and pressing the apply buttom in the child form; so the system does all the observing you need.

Assuming that you store each instance of person as the `ListViewItem.Tag`, wouldn't it be enough and much easier to simply write a function in PersonDataForm :

```
 public void displayPerson(ListViewItem aPerson )
 {
   if (currentPerson.Tag is person)
   {
     currentPerson= aPerson;
     textBox1.Text = ((person)currentPerson.Tag).firstName;
     textBox2.Text = ((person)currentPerson.Tag).lastName;
   }
```

that displays the data in the textboxes and stores the `ListViewItem` in a variable `currentPerson` and gets called on `listViewPersons_Click` ?

And to bring back changes you could have code in your apply button as simple as

```
private void cb_apply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (currentPerson!= null)
  {
    ((person)currentPerson.Tag).firstName = textBoxFirstName.Text;
    ((person)currentPerson.Tag).lastName = textBoxLastName.Text;
    curPerson.Text = ((person)currentPerson.Tag).ToString();
  }
}
```

Your two forms are tightly coupled, one being meant to support the other directly.

As Understand it, the IObservable is meant for cases where either the coupling is rather loose, needs to be expandable over classes, supports varying numbers of subscribers and/or doesn't have any conection to the regular event queue. But maybe I am wrong here..

Comment: But how do i pass (ListViewItem person) between forms? I don't quite understand.

Comment: To child form I could pass the data in contractor: pdfrm = new PersonDataForm(ListViewItem person); but every click on item I would reload the form. And how to pass it back to main form?

Comment: Since you pass a reference any changes there will reflect, more or less automatically in the ListView.  Note, that I have added one line to also change the visible label text, assuming that your person class has a ToString method that can display a nice formatted person..  Also note that I had left out the Tag and used the class name person by mistake as the parameter name. sorry..

Comment: This way I have to pass the reference from MainForm to PersonDataForm in constructor  pdfrm = new PersonDataForm((person)currentPerson.Tag)) and reload constructor on item click.

Comment: No, there is no other reference passing involved except passing the ListViewItem. And the MainForm __keeps__ a reference to the PersonDataForm. To load a person on opening you could simply call the dispalyPerson method when appropriate. Also consider using the `SelectedIndexChanged` instead of  the `Click` event to allow for keyboard selection.

Comment: I see. From MainForm to  PersonDataForm it works good :             private void   listViewPersons_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      hdfrm.DisplayPerson(listViewPersons.SelectedItems[0]);
         }                                                                   But how can I initialize currentPerson in  cb_apply_Click method?

Comment: _But how can I initialize currentPerson in cb_apply_Click method?_  You don't __initialize__ it; it's tag already contains a perfectly good person as it __is__ the LVI from the ListView, so all you need to do is update that. Note: I have completed the code, refresh the page to see it..

Comment: Wow! Awesome! Now I get it! It works very good! Thank  you so much!

Comment: Now I know about the checkmark. I didn't find where can I upvote your reputation.